# Given an input N, complete the function evenNumbers() to return all even numbers in the range [0, N] in the form of an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to return the array containing even numbers, from 0 to a given an integer N.

My actual code is :

```
function evenNumbers(n) {
    let i = 0;
    while(i <= n)
    i += 2;
    var ans = [];
    ans.push(0, n%2 === 0);
    return ans;
}
module.exports = evenNumbers;
console.log(evenNumbers(6));
```

Output :

```
[0, true]
```

But the expected output is :

```
[0, 2, 4, 6]
```

Why `evenNumbers()` doesn't return the expected result?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You are given an integer N. Output should be "Return the array containing even numbers."

Comment: Sample input:-  6

Should return output as below,
Sample output:- [0, 2, 4, 6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set `ans=[]` and `i=0` at the beginning
2. Using a `while-loop`, iterate as long as `i <= n`
3. In each iteration, add `i` to `ans` and increment it by `2`
4. In the end, after the loop finishes, return `ans`

```js
function evenNumbers(n) {
  const ans = [];
  let i = 0;
  while(i <= n) { 
    ans.push(i);
    i += 2;
  }
  return ans;
}

console.log('Even numbers 0-2: ', ...evenNumbers(2));
console.log('Even numbers 0-6: ', ...evenNumbers(6));
```